# Are workflows guaranteed to execute in a FIFO order? (CRM 2011 RU18 on-prem)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, microsoft-dynamics

Is it safe to assume that async workflows will execute in the order they were triggered? For e.g.

WF1 on custom object gets triggered.
WF1 causes WF2 and WF3 to get triggered in that order i.e. they both go to the async queue.

Can I safely assume WF2 will actually execute before WF3?

I couldn't find anything official that talk about this so maybe shouldn't assume?

Comment: If you have such interweaving logic, better to do everything in async plugin sequentially. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that it will be FIFO. Async services can process the async jobs in an order of available resources.

> Any asynchronous operation that has a `AsyncOperation.DependencyToken` value of **null** executes independent of all other asynchronous operations in the queue. The order of execution with regard to other independent operations is not guaranteed. However, ***asynchronous operations created earlier have a better chance of executing before operations created later***. This assumes that the operations are not postponed and are not set to a state of Completed.
>
> The dependency token must be set when the asynchronous operation is created. Because Dynamics 365 creates asynchronous operations for bulk operations such as bulk email, bulk delete, and import, you cannot make use of the dependency token for these operations. In addition, the dependency token cannot be used to order execution of asynchronous registered plug-ins because the asynchronous operation that executes plug-ins is created by the Queue Manager.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/dependency-execution-order-asynchronous-operations)

Activate means different in CRM WF case. I assume you are talking about triggering WF. If the WF2 and WF3 are triggered as child WF sequentially inside WF1, then Dependency token will be issued by platform accordingly to go in order. ie first WF2 then WF3.

Comment: GREAT answer! thanks and regarding comment above, I've been asked to implement custom logic as custom workflow activities and was pondering how to break it up into manageable chunks, hence the original question.

Comment: updated question to use triggered instead of activated to avoid confusion